# I deleted my question, how can I un-delete it?

Tags: support, status-completed, questions, deleted-questions

I accidentally deleted one of my questions instead of editing it.  Now I can't recreate it because it says it is a duplicate and can't edit it because it's not found.

This is the question page: [Creating tree view with jQuery jTemplates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12395384/creating-tree-view-with-jquery-jtemplates)

How can I un-delete my question?

Comment: Can you see that page?(deleted question)

Comment: no i can't (page not found)

Comment: @baba-dev: I just flagged your question for undeletion

Comment: @baba-dev I just seconded Mat. 1 more and it is back.

Comment: @Mat Should we flag such questions(this question on Meta) as *too localized*.

Comment: It is undeleted.

Comment: thank you all for helping

Comment: @hims056: the [support] tag is for this type of question. OP cannot reach the deleted post since that requires 10k rep. Only 10k users can vote to undelete, and only mods & SE staff can undelete directly. (The OP could have flagged another post with a detailed explanation, but that's about the only recourse.) A mod here will resolve and/or close the meta question if/when necessary.

Comment: I wish [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2645/176533) was re-considered.